# macOS documentation for structs in Security.h

Tags: c, macos, struct, jna

I'm trying to use the `Security.h` macOS framework via Java and JNA. That means I need to reconstruct certain structs as Java classes.

The problem is, when I look at the docs for a struct ([this one](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/seckeychainitemref?language=objc), for example), all I see is a brief description of the struct without any mention of its fields. Where can I get a full description of a struct in Apple's documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick look, you can find the headers on [Apple's open source site](https://opensource.apple.com/), but it's difficult to navigate, especially as the headers are under different locations depending on the version of the OS you want to check. In all cases I've found it's defined in `SecBase.h`. For example [here is the one for latest macOS](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-57740.51.3/base/SecBase.h.auto.html).

And there you get this:

```
typedef struct CF_BRIDGED_TYPE(id) SECTYPE(SecKeychainItem) *SecKeychainItemRef;
```

So you'll probably need other headers to track down the exact fields of the struct. A better way to do that would be to install XCode with frameworks for the OS you want, and you'll get the headers on your local system. For example:

```
$ ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/*.platform/Developer/SDKs/*.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS2.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator2.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h
```

I don't have a good solution with the online docs, though.

Another way, from memory it was more helpful for the task of recreating the struct in Java for JNA, would be to build a minimal C program (But I'm not sure how to do that on macOS, linking with Security framework, perhaps you do), and **give it to gdb to print the structure layout** using `ptype`:

```
(gdb) whatis v
type = struct complex
(gdb) ptype v
type = struct complex {
    double real;
    double imag;
}
```

But as noted in comments, if we try this here, we get this:

```
(gdb) ptype SecKeychainItemRef
type = struct OpaqueSecKeychainItemRef {
  <incomplete type>
}
```

I'm afraid this symbol is voluntarily made opaque... Confirmed by Brendan in comments:

> every macOS type I can think of that ends in `Ref` is an opaque type
>   (really a pointer), only meant to be passed to functions

Here is a debug session with Xcode: [image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: Wow. I didn't think the question "Where are the docs?" would have such a long answer. It sounds like the fields are not part of the public api and thus subject to change. Is that right? Oh, and you can link to a framework with e.g. `gcc -framework Security`.

Comment: I... got carried away :) I've done this for JNA some time ago but never on macOS, so I got curious. Btw I tried `ptype SecKeychainItemRef` but all I got was `type = struct OpaqueSecKeychainItemRef { <incomplete type>} *` :(
So yeah it seems the fields are private API and even hidden or something.

Comment: I don't think this is a iron-clad documented rule, but every macOS type I can think of that ends in `Ref` is an opaque type (really a pointer), only meant to be passed to functions.

Comment: I guess the right way to handle a type like this is to just use the `Pointer` class. Thanks, this is a very thorough answer.